# In Swift, how bad it is to declare variable in loops

Tags: swift

I don't know all Swift mechanics, and how it handles variables.

I always preferred to declare variables before entering a `for` or `while` loop, not matter the language, rather than declaring them inside the loop over and over.

But is it that bad to re-declare variables ? Would it affect performance with a very large iteration ? How does **specifically Swift** handle this behavior ?

example :

```
while i < 100 {
  let a = someFunc()
  i += 1
}
```

VS

```
let a: MyObj
while i < 100 {
 a = someFunc()
 i += 1
}
```

Comment: It's usually best to declare variables in the smallest scope possible.

Comment: @rmaddy so you would pick the first example ?

Comment: Absolutely. It avoids possible bugs and makes it clear where the variable is used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would not impact performance, and version 1 is highly preferred. Even if it would impact performance, you would need to demonstrate that on your precise code before you would consider any other option but version 1. There are no universal performance answers when dealing with an optimizing compiler. Doing anything unusual "for performance" that you have not deeply explored with your code runs a high likelihood of making things worse. The normal cases are the most optimized cases.

(I know I'm overstating this. There are definitely ways to look at code and say "that's going to be horribly inefficient." And there are some quirky parts of Swift where things that look ok are in fact bad, most notably using `+` to combine strings, or using pre-Swift4 `reduce` to create an array. But in the cases that those matter, you're going to discover it really quickly because they're *really* bad when they matter.)

But we don't have to guess about any of this. We can just ask the compiler.

```
// inside.swift
import Foundation

func runme() {
    var i = 0
    while i < 100 {
      let a = Int.random(in: 0...10)
      print(a)
      i += 1
    }
}


// outside.swift
import Foundation

func runme() {
    var i = 0
    var a: Int
    while i < 100 {
      a = Int.random(in: 0...10)
      print(a)
      i += 1
    }
}
```

First, note that I put these in a function. That's important. Putting them at the top level makes `a` a global in one case, and globals have special handling, including thread-safe initialization, which makes the "outside" case look more expensive and complicated than it would be in more normal usage. (It is very, very hard to correctly test micro-optimizations in such a way that you can draw general "this is faster" conclusions. There are so many factors.)

Second notice the `print`. We need to make sure to use `a` in a side-effecty way, or else the optimizer might remove it entirely. `print` is pretty good, even though it's quite complicated. You can also use the result to modify a global, but the compiler could definitely optimize that much more aggressively and might eliminate things we wanted to see. (You *really* **really** have to test this stuff on the actual case you care about.)

Now we can see what Swift is going to do with each of these using `swiftc -O -emit-sil`. That `-O` is critical. So many people try to do performance testing without turning on the optimizer, and those results are beyond meaningless.

So what's the SIL look like? (Swift Intermediate Language. This is the first big step towards turning your program into machine code. If two things generate the same SIL, they're going to generate the same machine code.)

The SIL is a little long (8000 lines), so I'm going to trim it a bit. My comments in <>. This is going to get a little tedious, because exploring this stuff is very nitpicky. If you want to skip it, the TL-DR is: there's no difference between these two pieces of code. Not "a small difference that won't matter." Literally (except for a hint to the debugger), no difference.

```
// runme()
sil hidden @$S4main5runmeyyF : $@convention(thin) () -> () {
bb0:
  ... <define a bunch of variables and function calls> ...

<compute the random number and put it in %29>
// %19                                            // user: %49
bb1(%19 : $Builtin.Int64):                        // Preds: bb5 bb0
  %20 = alloc_stack $SystemRandomNumberGenerator  // users: %23, %30, %21
  store %2 to %20 : $*SystemRandomNumberGenerator // id: %21
  br bb2                                          // id: %22

bb2:                                              // Preds: bb3 bb1
  %23 = apply %6<SystemRandomNumberGenerator>(%20, %5) : $@convention(method) <τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 : RandomNumberGenerator> (@inout τ_0_0, @thin UInt.Type) -> UInt // user: %24
  %24 = struct_extract %23 : $UInt, #UInt._value  // users: %28, %25
  %25 = builtin "cmp_ult_Int64"(%24 : $Builtin.Int64, %4 : $Builtin.Int64) : $Builtin.Int1 // user: %26
  cond_br %25, bb3, bb4                           // id: %26

bb3:                                              // Preds: bb2
  br bb2                                          // id: %27

bb4:                                              // Preds: bb2
  %28 = builtin "urem_Int64"(%24 : $Builtin.Int64, %3 : $Builtin.Int64) : $Builtin.Int64 // user: %29
  %29 = struct $Int (%28 : $Builtin.Int64)        // users: %42, %31
  dealloc_stack %20 : $*SystemRandomNumberGenerator // id: %30


< *** Note that %29 is called "a" *** >

  debug_value %29 : $Int, let, name "a"           // id: %31

... < The print call. This is a lot more code than you think it is...> ...

< Add one to i and check for overflow >

  %49 = builtin "sadd_with_overflow_Int64"(%19 : $Builtin.Int64, %8 : $Builtin.Int64, %13 : $Builtin.Int1) : $(Builtin.Int64, Builtin.Int1) // users: %51, %50
  %50 = tuple_extract %49 : $(Builtin.Int64, Builtin.Int1), 0 // users: %55, %53
  %51 = tuple_extract %49 : $(Builtin.Int64, Builtin.Int1), 1 // user: %52
  cond_fail %51 : $Builtin.Int1                   // id: %52


< Loop if i < 100 >
  %53 = builtin "cmp_slt_Int64"(%50 : $Builtin.Int64, %1 : $Builtin.Int64) : $Builtin.Int1 // user: %54
  cond_br %53, bb5, bb6                           // id: %54

bb5:                                              // Preds: bb4
  br bb1(%50 : $Builtin.Int64)                    // id: %55

bb6:                                              // Preds: bb4
  %56 = tuple ()                                  // user: %57
  return %56 : $()                                // id: %57
} // end sil function '$S4main5runmeyyF'
```

The "outside" code is almost identical. What's different? Note where the `***` in the code above marking the call to `debug_value`? That's missing in "outside" because `a` is defined as a function variable rather than a block variable.

Know what's missing in both of these? An `alloc_stack` call for "a". It's an integer; it can fit in a register. It's up to the lower level compiler whether it's stored in a register or the stack. The optimizer sees that "a" doesn't escape this region of the code, so it includes a hint for the debugger, but it doesn't actually bother to demand storage for it, not even on the stack. It can just take the return register of `Random` and move it to the parameter register for `print`. It's up to LLVM and its optimizer to decide all this.

The lesson from all this is that it literally doesn't matter for performance. In obscure cases where it might matter (such as when `a` is a global), version 1 would be more efficient, which I assume is the opposite of what you were expecting.

Answer (score 6):

Swift handles this like most languages handle it. Local variables are declared on the stack, and popped off the stack when you exit the scope where they are defined. Pushing to and popping off of the stack is a very low-cost operation.

The LLVM compiler that Swift uses uses quite advanced code optimization, especially in release mode. In your trivial example the variables you're using the variables might well be optimized away anyway, since they aren't actually used for anything.

### EDIT:

To summarize, there is no meaningful performance difference between the 2, and the first approach of putting the variable inside the loop is cleaner, as stated by rmaddy in his comment. Defining variables in the narrowest scope possible is a good policy. It shows your intent for the variable, and avoids unintended consequences.

Comment: I know that this isn't something that would make a slow program become a "fast" one, but I was just curious about the performance of it. And for my example, it's just a very simple case, in real life obviously we would do something with the variables !